# Concat 2 column data through another column (group by)

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

My Table - Education

```
State    Code   Descr

AA       001    aaaaaa
AA       002    aaaabbb
BB       003    qwerty
CC       025    asdfg
BB       014    zsedc
AA       015    lknhj
CC       084    uhygt
CC       067    fdrda
```

I want it in below format:

State    Code

```
AA       001-aaaaaa,002-aaaabbb,015-lknhj

BB       003-qwerty,014-zsedc**

CC       025-asdfg,084-uhygt,067-fdrda
```

I am trying and succeded in getting column "Code" in single row by below query:

```
select state,
replace(wm_concat(code), ',', ',') CODE
from education
group by state
order by state;
```

**Output:**

```
State    Code

AA       001,002,015

BB       003,014

CC       025,084,067
```

And also I have got respective `descr` for each `code` through below query:

```
select state, concat(concat(replace(wm_concat(code),',',','), '-'),descr) CODE
from education
group by state,descr
order by state
```

Can you help me club-up the queries to get the desired output.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wont this help ?

```
select state,
replace(wm_concat(code||'-'||descr), ',', ',') CODE
from education
group by state
order by state;
```

if Oracle 11g, it can be

```
select state,
LISTAGG(code||'-'||descr,',') (WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY code) as CODE
from education
group by state
order by state;
```

Comment: Thank you !! !!!! I also tried and got below working code: 
select state, wm_concat(concat(concat(code, '-'),descr)) CODE from education group by state order by state